# MainActivity not detecting/working for some reason

Tags: java, android

It probably had something to do with the gradle or jdk?
It displays error on @Overide, Strings, android methods.
I'm still new to this and there's this error. I tried to install gradle 6.7 but the MainActivity can't read Andriod Methods--

```
Unsupported Java. 
Your build is currently configured to use Java 17.0.2 and Gradle 6.8.

Possible solution:
 - Upgrade Gradle wrapper to 6.7 version and re-import the project
> package com.example.amedina.helloworld;
```

> import android.os.Bundle; import android.app.Activity; import
> android.util.Log; import com.example.amedina.helloworld.*;
>
> public class MainActivity extends Activity {
> String msg = "Android : ";
>
> ```
> /** Called when the activity is first created. */
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(com.example.tutorialspoint7.myapplication.R.layout.activity_main);
>     Log.d(msg, "The onCreate() event");
> }
>
> /** Called when the activity is about to become visible. */
> @Override
> protected void onStart() {
>     super.onStart();
>     Log.d(msg, "The onStart() event");
> }
>
> /** Called when the activity has become visible. */
> @Override
> protected void onResume() {
>     super.onResume();
>     Log.d(msg, "The onResume() event");
> }
>
> /** Called when another activity is taking focus. */
> @Override
> protected void onPause() {
>     super.onPause();
>     Log.d(msg, "The onPause() event");
> }
>
> /** Called when the activity is no longer visible. */
> @Override
> protected void onStop() {
>     super.onStop();
>     Log.d(msg, "The onStop() event");
> }
>
> /** Called just before the activity is destroyed. */
> @Override
> public void onDestroy() {
>     super.onDestroy();
>     Log.d(msg, "The onDestroy() event");
> } }
> ```

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) use R file of your own package and click on link - Upgrade Gradle wrapper to 6.7 version and re-import the project. It will update gradle plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try build-> Clean Project, then Rebuild Project.